# Error Export Module in Node.js - separation of concerns

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to implement separation of concerns by using export module. All the code is working if used without separation of concern but as soon as I am trying to import `generateUrlArray()` from `const db = require('../db')` nothing is working. Nodejs is not giving me any error on the back-end. The error I am getting on front-end is `Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input` . I am positive that the error is coming from back-end. Let me know if you have any ideas.

**controller.js**

```
const db = require('../db')

exports.getWebApiList = (req, res) => {
  (async function fetchDataList() {
    try {
      const urlArray = await db.generateUrlArray({}, { _id: 0 })
      return res.send(urlArray)
    } catch (ex) {
      console.log(`fetchDataList error: ${ex}`)
    }
  })()
}
```

**..db/index.js**

```
const { List } = require('./models/List')

const generateUrlArray = (query, projection) => {
  const dataFromDB = List.find(query, projection).select('symbol')
  return linkArray = dataFromDB.map(item => {
    return link = `https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=GLOBAL_QUOTE&symbol=${item.symbol}&apikey=6BUYSS9QR8Y9HH15`
  })
}

module.exports = { generateUrlArray }
```

**.models/List.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise
const ParentSchemaSymbolList = new mongoose.Schema({
  symbol: String
})
module.exports.List = mongoose.model('List', ParentSchemaSymbolList)
```

Comment: Does `dataFromDB` return something? (please check)

Comment: `index.js` file is imported from `db` folder Nodejs will recognize it if it is named `index`

Comment: @AlexOwl `dataFromDb` is returning an array

Comment: Please check what you are sending to client `urlArray` is it json valid?

Comment: @AlexOwl alreadt tried not working.

Comment: I don't really know how to help you without all the environment, I can't reproduce your problem

Comment: @AlexOwl noworries. Thank you for trying!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189974/discussion-between-alexowl-and-john-john).

Comment: @AlexOwl you have the answer. if you do not mind to post it I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const generateUrlArray = async (query, projection) => {
  const dataFromDB = await List.find(query, projection).select('symbol')
  const linkArray = dataFromDB.map(item => {
    return link = `https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=GLOBAL_QUOTE&symbol=${item.symbol}&apikey=6BUYSS9QR8Y9HH15`
  })
  return linkArray
}
```